# symfony 1.4 propel 1.6 : sum

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sum, propel

I'm trying to get a sum of columns in propel. My code

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(valuePeer::OWNER_ID, $this->getId());
$c->addSelectColumn('SUM(' . valuePeer::VALUE . ') as total');
$c->addGroupByColumn(valuePeer::VALUE);

$sum = valuePeer::DoSelect($c);
```

printing out `$sum` returns nothing (not even an empty object). all i get is `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /.../lib/model/om/BaseValue.php on line 203 Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /.../lib/model/om/BaseValue.php on line 204`

I tried this approach with `::DoSelectRS($c)` as suggested [here](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/20554/) and multiple other discussions but i get an error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method ValuePeer::DoSelectRS() in /.../lib/model/Restauracia.php on line 39`.

Can anyone please tell me what is the right approach on this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just found this solution. it works like i needed.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->add(valuePeer::OWNER_ID, $this->getId());
$c->addSelectColumn('SUM(' . valuePeer::VALUE . ') as total');
//$c->addGroupByColumn(valuePeer::VALUE);

$sum = valuePeer::DoSelectStmt($c)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
$sum = $sum[0];
```

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use the new ModelCriteria instead of the old verbose one ?

```
$sum = ValueQuery::create()
  ->select(array('total'))
  ->filterByOwnerId($this->getId())
  ->withColumn('SUM(Value.Value)', 'total')
  ->find();
```

Will return something like:

```
PropelArrayCollection(
  array('total' => 25)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Don't worry about `findOne`,  `SUM` returns one row anyway).

Note that `getTotal()` is generated from reference 'total' of withColumn.

The convention is `get+Columnname` ( camelcase )

```
$sum = ValueQuery::create()
  ->filterByOwnerId($this->getId())
  ->withColumn('SUM(Value.Value)', 'total')
  ->findOne()
  ->getTotal();
```